# Android Recycler view not refreshing from service

Tags: java, android

I have an adapter for my recycler view.
I then go and instantiate this adapter in an activity where I populate the recycler view. In my project I have a background service which is always running and it executes a delete functionality from Firebase Realtime Database. The delete works perfectly fine the problem is I am not able to refresh the adapter like I normally do. My usual course of action for the refreshing the recycler view is calling ->
`notifyDataSetChanged()` which works like a charm.

How can I refresh my recycler view every time the delete functionality is triggered in my background service.

I have tried creating an instance of the adapter class and calling notifyDataSetChanged but this is not working for me sadly.
Any advice or guidance would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

You need to have a **callback** from the service to your activity

You **cannot** create a new instance of the adapter class and calling notifyDataSetChanged in the service, because it **different** instance from the instance of adapter class in the activity

Here some [tutorial](https://medium.com/@sahityakumarsuman/android-service-communication-with-activity-2c01e537ab03) to do it or you can use [EventBus](https://github.com/greenrobot/EventBus)

Comment: Thank you I will look into this now

Comment: I am having difficulty trying to apply the above tutorial to my situation would another viable solution be to refresh the current fragment from the background service when the delete is triggered